# Calling MySQL Stored Procedure with escaped database name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using MySQL: 5.1.69

I have created stored procedures and called them many times. In this case, I appear to have hit a snag related to escape characters in the schema name.

our MySQL database / schema is named like this: `www.company.com`

Due to this, we must always escape the database name like this: `` `www.company.com`.table_name ``

I have created a procedure from within MySQLWorkbench

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_backfill_data
(p_var1 INT(11)
,p_var2 DATETIME)
BEGIN
/*do lots of work here*/
END
```

And from within MySQL Workbench I am able to call the procedure using:

```
use `www.company.com`;
CALL usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');
```

Under these conditions the procedure works exactly as expected.

However, when I try to call the procedure from the command line:

```
%> mysql -uuser -ppassword -Dwww.company.com -e "CALL usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');"
```

or when I try

```
%> mysql -uuser -ppassword -e "CALL \`www.company.com\`.usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');"
```

or when I log into the mysql command line and use:

```
mysql> use `www.company.com`;
mysql> CALL usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');
```

I *always* get the following error:

```
ERROR 1305 (42000) at line 1: PROCEDURE www.company.com.usp_backfill_data does not exist
```

I am hoping that there is something super obvious that I'm overlooking here.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: What do you get from 'show procedure status'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To escape database name in command line use double quotes

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword -D"www.company.com" -e "CALL usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');"
                            ^               ^
```

Other two methods

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword -e "CALL \`www.company.com\`.usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');"
```

and

```
$ mysql -uuser -ppassword
mysql> USE `www.company.com`;
Database changed
mysql> CALL usp_backfill_data(5000, '2012-01-01');
```

work for me just fine

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond.

I have tried the suggested method and it still does not work. This leaves me thinking it must be a permissions issue.

I am marking this question as answered as peterm proved that the issue is not in how I am calling the prodcedure